# How can i delete a commit on github which i committed 3 days before without losing later data?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I committed some file 3 days before but now i want to remove that commit(or delete files included in that commit specifically if possible) without losing any data after or before that date.if that's possible please Help.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest will probably be to [`revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) it. It will create a new commit at the tip of current branch, which the exact opposite changes your bad commit brought.

```
git revert <commitHash>
```

Comment: Nice. I've always done it through patching `git diff commit prev-commit > patch.txt`, and `git apply patch.txt`. Didn't know revert was a thing. This is slick.